# Update view after async API call with RxSwift

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift

I'm trying to add RxSwift to a peace of code using MVVM pattern. My app need to get a list of FoodType (desert, meal, etc.) an Food from an API and save them to Realm database. Then, I have a view with an UITextField and a UIButton.

The user write a food type (ex: desert):

- Background: the app should get FoodType and FoodList from Api if not in Realm DB
- On button click: show list of Food that have the FoodType chosen by the user from Realm

**ViewModel**

```
struct FoodTypeViewModel { 

    // Get datas from API   
    private func getFoods() {
        foodService.getAll(completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let foods):
                for food in foods {
                    food.save()
                }
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
                break
            }
        })
    }

    // Get datas from API   
    private func getFoodTypes() {
        foodService.getAll(completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let foodTypes):
                for type in types {
                    type.save()
                }
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
                break
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class SetupViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var foodTypeTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var foodTypeButton: UIButton!
}
```

***Model***

```
class FoodType: Object {
    dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    dynamic var fullName: String?
    let foods = List<Food>()
}
```

I would like to add RxSwift to that code but how can I handle the asynchronous API. On first start the app have no datas (I don't want to populate at start) but when the user click the button. So on button click, UI should wait the response from the service (using waiting animation) and ViewModel should update UI when service respond. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a generic return object to wrap communication errors.

```
enum APIResult<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}
```

Then, convert your completion handler to return an `Observable`:

```
func getFoods() -> Observable<APIResult<[FoodType]>> {
    return Observable<APIResult<[FoodType]>>.create { observer -> Disposable in
        self.foodService.getAll(completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let foods):
                observer.onNext(.success(foods))
                break
            case .Failure(let error):
                observer.onNext(.error(error))
                break
            }
            observer.onCompleted()

            return Disposables.create()
        })
    }
}
```

Now simply process the observable as any other in RxSwift.

```
getFoods().subscribe(onNext: { result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let foods):
            print("Received foods: \(foods)")
            break
        case .error(let error):
            print("Received error: \(error)")
            break
    }
}.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

---

Using [these utility classes](https://gist.github.com/redent/0fd56a47d7dfa3308cdbbb77eaa79c3d) will help you mapping success results and split error and success signals to different observables. For example:

```
let foodsRequest = getFoods().splitSuccess

foodsRequest.error.subscribe(onNext: { error in
    print("Received error: \(error)")
})

foodsRequest.success.subscribe(onNext: { foods in
    print("Received foods: \(foods)")
}
```

---

You can also convert Realm objects to RxSwift observables:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.objects(Lap).asObservable()
  .subscribeNext {[weak self] laps in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Take a look at [*Using Realm Seamlessly in an RxSwift App*](https://realm.io/news/marin-todorov-realm-rxswift/) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks but is it the best way to handle Realm ? I mean, I believed there is a way to only use local storage during app life. The API only communicate with DB and views react to DB changes. In your case I should wait for datas from API. Do you understand what I mean ? Btw, thanks for this very nice answer and for the classes!

Comment: @Ludovic You can also bind local database changes as observables. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!